# Message Processor for JMS Queue without Message Store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is it possible to send JMS Messages to a JMS Queue in Message Broker to be further processed by a Message Processor without a Message Store?

e.g.

```
    <resource methods="PUT" uri-template="/{itemName}">
    <inSequence>
        <property name="transport.jms.ContentTypeProperty" value="Content-Type" scope="axis2"/>
        <property name="HTTP_METHOD" expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_METHOD')" scope="transport" type="STRING"></property>
        <property expression="json-eval($.barcode)" name="uri.var.barcode" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <log level="full">
            <property expression="get-property('uri.var.barcode')" name="barcode"/>
        </log>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
                {"barcode": "$1"}
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.barcode')"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="jms:/myqueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=conf/jndi.properties&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue&amp;transport.jms.ContentTypeProperty=ContentType"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
</resource>
```

Say I have a simple API that received a JSON body and I want to send it to a queue called myqueue, I would like a Message Processor to read the messages for further processing.

Or perhaps is there some other way to achieve a similar concept?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is merely to consume messages from a particular queue for further processing, the following could be a better fit rather than message processors, which have been designed to be used with message stores storing messages temporarily:

- JMS Inbound Endpoints (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Sample+901%3A+Inbound+Endpoint+JMS+Protocol+Sample)
- JMS Listener Proxy
  (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/The+ESB+Profile+of+WSO2+Enterprise+Integrator+as+a+JMS+Consumer)